# Where am I wrong? Writing to file PHP

Tags: php

```
while (!feof($file1) && $linecount++<$requiredLines) { 

        $line = stream_get_line($file1, $filesize, PHP_EOL ); 

        fwrite($file2,$line);
    }
```

How to make it to write every line on new line?
Like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I have tried this way but then i do not fulfill the condition:

```
while (!feof($file1) && $linecount++<$requiredLines) { 

        $line = stream_get_line($file1, $filesize, '\n' ); 

        fwrite($file2,$line);
    }
```

My idea is to write 10 or more lines but to be on new line every time.

Comment: It's `"\n"`, not `'\n'`... And you have to concatenate the ending to the line. That third, optional argument serves a different purpose: detecting a line end in the file you read from.

Comment: Reading ends when length bytes have been read, **when the string specified by ending is found (which is not included in the return value)**, or on EOF (whichever comes first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line terminator yourself:

```
fwrite($file2, $line."\n");
```

Note that escape characters are *not* interpreted in [single-quote strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), and you must use a double-quote string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Amazing. I got three up votes for a totally broken answer before someone pointed it out. Thank you, I've corrected my mistake. (I use Python much more than PHP now and thought it was only variable expansion that was controlled by quote styles.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Also don't mix languages :) In PHP you use `.` for concatenation and not `+`.

Comment: @Rizier123 my god, who up-voted this crap? I've made the answer community wiki as I clearly have no idea how to use PHP anymore and don't deserve the rep!

Comment: Thanks to all! Working perfect